# I want to chat with friends, but not hear game sound/volume?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-network

I recently got some TurtleBeach XL1 headphones. How can I configure them to only hear the party and not game sounds?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How can I hook up xl1 to hear and talk to party, not game sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Go into the game's audio options and turn all the sliders to zero. The game will emit no sound, and you'll be able to talk to your friends.

Comment: Not sure this addresses the "they said that they could not hear me" portion of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well, I meant that when I had a bad mic, they could not hear me, Thanks for the answer, and will I still be able to hear the game volume from the tv?

Comment: @user1544217 Try to state all your requirements in the original question. This isn't a forum, where back and forth conversation is expected. Your question should include all the required information (and nothing more).